# styled(Component) not passing style values down to custom components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a React Component `Knob` and want to pass different styles to it, to place it multiple times in a CSS grid. The parent component has `Display: grid` and the children are styled like this:

```
const Treble = styled(Knob)`
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
`;

const Mid = styled(Knob)`
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
`;
...
```

But unfortunately the grid values are not being passed down to the Knob component. If I place the grid values on the top most Container of the Knob Component (which is styled by styled-components as well), it does work as expected. Can anybody tell me, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Does adding `{...this.props}` in `<Knob />` help? Like this `<Knob {...this.props} />`.

Comment: No, i just read the docu again and you have to pass the classname. I did not read that right the first tim ;) thanks, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i just read the docu again and figured out, that you have to pass the classname down to the parent component of the child components. So I changed the render() of the `Knob` into:

```
const {className} = this.props;
<Container className={className}>
   ...
</Container>
```